# Self-hosting ASP.NET Web-Api as Windows Service with Controllers in different project within solution

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I have an Web-Api project with controllers and all the necessary stuff, which I want to host as Windows Service.
I've created new project, and added there a `WindowsService` and `ServiceInstaller` items, so my solution looks like this:

[image: Solution structure]

My configuration is:

```
private HttpSelfHostServer _server;
    private readonly HttpSelfHostConfiguration _config;
    public const string ServiceAddress = "http://localhost:333";

    public WebApiService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(ServiceAddress);

        // Set our own assembly resolver where we add the assemblies we need
        CustomAssembliesResolver assemblyResolver = new CustomAssembliesResolver();
        _config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), assemblyResolver);

        _config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }

public class CustomAssembliesResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
    {
        public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
        {
            ICollection<Assembly> baseAssemblies = base.GetAssemblies();

            List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(baseAssemblies);

            var controllersAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"D:\Regula\WebApiService\WebApiService\bin\WebApiService.dll");

            baseAssemblies.Add(controllersAssembly);

            return assemblies;
        }
    }
```

I've tried to follow [this thread suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226671/selfhosted-aspnet-webapi-with-controller-classes-in-different-project), but it did not help me - I'm still getting:

> No type was found that matches the controller named 'Home'.

Basically, I' trying to call `HomeController`
located in `WebApiService` project from `WebApiHost` project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code for `CustomAssembliesResolver` seems relevant.

Comment: It's copy/pasted from the thread I've specified in my post, just with target assembly path changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MapHttpRoute` is for controllers, derived from `ApiController` only. `HomeController` is derived from `Controller`, so it can't be mapped in this way.