# ASP.Net WebAPI controller in separate Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a new large Web Application using ASP.NET Web API. In that, I want to separate all controller classes into one [different class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226671/selfhosted-aspnet-webapi-with-controller-classes-in-different-project) from ASP.NET MVC project.. Please consider following options.

**Case 1 :** Keeping controllers in same ASP.NET MVC project

**Case 2 :** Separating controllers in separate class library

1. Is it right to go with **Case#1** as I think this controller can be reusable by other projects or hosting in windows service instead of IIS Web Application.
2. Also if in future if I want to access Web-API methods from Android,IPhone native apps then does it works for me in both cases  **Case#1** and **Case#2**
3. Is there any performance issue with **Case#2**.
4. What would be the best practice to register multiple controllers in both cases using UnityContainer.RegisterType ?

Comment: Careful of creating dependencies across DLLs, i.e. is that ok for you?

Comment: Many tiny assemblies delay load time, and unity isn't the fastest container out there...

Comment: Have a look here:
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/01/on-the-coexistence-of-asp-net-mvc-and-webapi.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Putting your Web API code in a different project than your MVC code should be a best practice.  There is no reason not to do it.